# cnn max pooling - non consecutive sliding window (skip gram like)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, convolution

When using keras to build a simple cnn like the code below and when it is used on text-based problems such as document classification, I understand that this is as if we are extracting 4-grams from the text (kernel_size of 4) and use them as features.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(embedding_layer)
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))      
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and in this case, the kernel size in the conv1D layer is like a sliding window of size 4 that walks over sequences of tokens in the text to emit 4-grams.

I wonder if here is a way such that we can create 'non-consecutive sliding window in the convolution, i.e., that would generate 'skip-gram' equivalent. So for example, given the following 1d vector:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

a conv1d with a kernel_size=3 skip=1 will scan the following sequences:

```
[(a,c,d),(b,d,e),(c,e,f),(d,f,padding),(e,padding,padding)] union [(a,b,d),(b,c,e),(c,d,f),(d,e,padding),(e,f,padding),(f,padding,padding)]
```

The reason I say 'union' is simply because I suppose from the implementation point of view, it may be easier to generate either part 1 or part 2, giving another parameter for the revised conv1d layer. and if thhat's the case and doable, I can work around this by concatenating multiple layers. But the minimum is really to have an extended conv1d layer that would take additional parameters such that it does either the first or the second part of scanning.

The idea is not new as this paper already experimented it: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D/D16/D16-1085.pdf

But excuse my lack of in-depth knowledge of keras I do not know how to implement it. Any suggestions please,

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is this regularly skipping tokens with a fixed step? Or are you defining the specific tokens to be skipped?

Comment: Do you mean skip 1, read 3, skip 1, read 3, skip 1, read 3....?

Comment: yes it is regularly skipping but not quite like what you described in the second reply. I have revised the question with a detailed example. So it is like you have a window with a gap of a certain size to ignore certain elements

Comment: Following your update (different channels skip different grams), I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this creating a custom convolutional layer where certain elements in the weight matrix are zero.

You can take the regular `Conv1D` layer as the base class.

But before doing this, notice that you can create a "dilated" convolution by passing the `dilation_rate=n` parameter when creating a regular convolutional layer. This will skip `n-1` grams between each taken gram in the window. Your window will have fixed regular spaces.

Creating a custom layer for that:

```
import keras.backend as K


#a 1D convolution that skips some entries
class SkipConv1D(Conv1D):

    #in the init, let's just add a parameter to tell which grams to skip
    def __init__(self, validGrams, **kwargs):

        #for this example, I'm assuming validGrams is a list
        #it should contain zeros and ones, where 0's go on the skip positions
        #example: [1,1,0,1] will skip the third gram in the window of 4 grams   
        assert len(validGrams) == kwargs.get('kernel_size')
        self.validGrams = K.reshape(K.constant(validGrams),(len(validGrams),1,1))
            #the chosen shape matches the dimensions of the kernel
            #the first dimension is the kernel size, the others are input and ouptut channels


        #initialize the regular conv layer:
        super(SkipConv1D,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #here, the filters, size, etc, go inside kwargs, so you should use them named
        #but you may make them explicit in this __init__ definition
        #if you think it's more comfortable to use it like this


    #in the build method, let's replace the original kernel:
    def build(self, input_shape):

        #build as the original layer:
        super(SkipConv1D,self).build(input_shape)

        #replace the kernel   
        self.originalKernel = self.kernel
        self.kernel = self.validGrams * self.originalKernel
```

#### Be aware of some things that weren't taken care of in this answer:

The method `get_weights()` will still return the original kernel, not the kernel with the skipped mask. (It's possible to fix this, but there will be an extra work, if necessary, please tell me)

There are unused weights in this layer. This is a simple implementation. The focus here was to keep it the most similar possible to an existing Conv layer, with all its features. It's also possible to use only strictly necessary weights, but this will increase the complexity a lot, and require lots of rewriting of the keras original code for recreating all the original possibilities.

If your kernel_size is too long, it will be very boring to define the `validGrams` var. You may want to create a version that takes some skipped indices and then converts it in the type of list used above.

#### Different channels skipping different grams:

It's possible to do this inside a layer as well, if instead of using a `validGrams` with shape `(length,)`, you use one with shape `(length,outputFilters)`.

In this case, at the point where we create the validGrams matrix, we should reshape it like:

```
validGrams = np.asarray(validGrams)
shp = (validGrams.shape[0],1,validGrams.shape[1])
validGrams = validGrams.reshape(shp)
self.validGrams = K.constant(validGrams)
```

You can also simply use many parallel `SkipConv1D` with different parameters and then concatenate their results.

```
inputs = Input(yourInputShape)
out = embedding_layer(inputs)

out1 = SkipConv1D(filters=50,kernel_size=4,validGrams=[1,0,1,1])(out)
out2 = SkipConv1D(filters=50,kernel_size=4,validGrams=[1,1,0,1])(out)

out = Concatenate()([out1,out2]) #if using 'channels_first' use Concatenate(axis=1)
out = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(out)
out = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs,out)
```

Comment: thank you for the details. I will try dilated conv since although it does not implement exactly what I want it is similar and potentially useful. I will also try concatenating multiple skipconv1d layers each looking at a different shape of the skip gram, this seems to be an easier workaround than other  implementations you mentioned - i am not very familiar with the underlying implementation so this seems to be the safest option. I will report back in the next few days

Comment: there is one issue in the code: K.reshape, what is 'K'? Is it 'backend' as 'from keras import backend as K'?

Comment: Yes, it's `import keras.backend as K`.

Comment: I am getting an error that has a long stack trace but the ultimate cause says 'ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 4 from 1 for 'max_pooling1d_12/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,100].', when I build a model that concatenates 4 skipconv1d layers, each with kernel size=6 and with the following masks:[1,1,1,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1]. Following this is a max pooling layer with size=4. Error happens when 'model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))'. Not sure if this is detailed enough but just want to ask what could I have done wrong?

Comment: Am I right to suppose your sentence length is equal to 6? This error is clearly: the length of the data (after the convolution) is not enough for a pooling of length 4.

Comment: Can you add your `model.summary()` in the question?